# Multi-row and Multi-column LaTeX table, trouble with one column

Tags: tables

I don't know how to put the percentage column in the following screenshot.

[image: I don't know how to add the percentage column]

Here's what I've tried so far.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{Classification Table}
\label{tab:confusion-matrix}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{N=260}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries Predicted} \\
  \cline{3-4}
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & \thead{Absent Nomophobias} & \thead{Has Nomophobia}\\
  \hline 
  \multirowcell{2.7}{\bfseries Actual}
    & \thead{Absent Nomophobia} & 4 & 15\\
    \cline{2-4}
    & \thead{Has Nomophobia} & 3 & 238\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly is your problem and question?

Comment: Unrelated: Please note that you shouldn't use `center` inside of your `table`, it gives strange/inconsistent spacing, instead use `\centering`. If you need table-captions with a bit of space below, load the `caption` package if in `article` (more complex classes like `memoir` or KOMA-script classes have other means and you don't need to load `caption`).